# Javascript variables from previous page to use in form

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a small little form, we'll call it page 1, that sends the results to page 2 on submit. This works as expected. I echo the variables and I am able to see them.

Now what I want to do, or am trying to do, is take these variables and fill in the REAL / actual form with the data they filled in on page 1 that comes over.

I cannot figure out how to do it. This is what I have, and yes it is incorrect, as it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstname = <?php echo $_POST['MSM_firstname'] ?>;
    if (firstname == "") {var data-pht="First Name"; var valueFN="First Name";}
    else {var data-pht=firstname; var valueFN=firstname;}
    MSM_lastname = <?php echo $_POST['MSM_lastname'] ?>;
</script>
```

this is the first name of the form what I am trying to fill in. If I can figure this out, then everything else is the same.

```
<label>First Name (required)</label>
<input id="MSM_firstname" type="text" name="MSM_firstname" class="required" size="50" onClick="this.value='';" onFocus="this.select()" onBlur="this.value=!this.value?'First Name':this.value;" value=valueFN data-placeholdertext=data-pht />
```

I also want to have the `this.value?'First Name'` be the data from page 1; I'm not sure how to do that as a variable either.

Comment: thanks for the help Mr. Sullinger!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear to me what you are wishing to do, but I believe these 5 wee scripts embody what you described.  The tricky bit, is in DemPg2.php,
where the php variable is made available to JavaScript, WHILE DemPg2.php is being *manufactured* so to speak.  Then, the onload can use the name and we
can have JavaScript apply style to the input element.  Let me know if I misunderstood your question.  If on the other hand, this works for you,  ask about any parts you do not understand, as to why it works.

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
$Label = "First Name";
?>
<Title>TinyDemo1</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DemCSS.css"/>
</head>
<body id="BodyPg1">
<div id="AForm">
<label id="ThaLabel"><?php echo ($Label." (required)");?></label>
<form id="SendPreFilledData" action="DemPg2.php" method="post" name="PreFilled">
    <input id="ForTransfer" spellcheck="false" name="SomeName" tabindex="12" maxlength="43" />
    <button id="SendUserData" type="submit">Send It</button>
</form>
</div><!-- AForm -->
</body>
</html>


/*
DemCSS.css
*/
#BodyPg1{background-color: black;
    color:white;font-style:italic;height:
    auto;overflow: visible;}
#AForm{position:absolute;top:11%;left:8%;
width:29%;height:23%;
background-color:#332334;
border:2px solid red;}
#ThaLabel{position:absolute;top:5%;
left:12%;width:80%;height:19%;
background-color:gray;text-align:center;
padding-left:5px;font-size:14px;color:black;}
#ForTransfer{position:absolute;top:29%;left:12%;
width:60%;height:25%;}
#SendUserData{position:absolute;top:75%;left:72%;
width:20%;height:18%;text-align:center;
padding-left:5px;font-size:14px;color:navy;}

/*
DemPg2.php
*/
<!doctype html>
<?php
//  STEP 1.  Catch POST(s) from :: DemPg1.php
$WormholeNET=$_POST["SomeName"];
$Label = "First Name";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var MakeVariableVisibleToJavaScriptOnPageLOAD = <?php echo $WormholeNET; ?>;
</script>
<Title>TinyDemo2</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DemJS.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dem2CSS.css"/>
</head>
<body id="BodyPg1">
<div id="AForm">
<label id="ThaLabel"><?php echo ($Label." (required)");?></label>
<form id="SendPreFilledData" action="DemPg2.php" method="post" name="PreFilled">
<input id="ForTransfer" spellcheck="false" cols="20" rows="1" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $WormholeNET;?>" />
    <button id="SendUserData" type="submit">Send It</button>
</form>
</div><!-- AForm -->
</body>
</html>

/*
Dem2CSS.css
*/
#BodyPg1 {background-color:black;color:white;
    font-style:italic;height:auto;overflow:visible;}
#AForm{position:absolute;top:11%;left:8%;
width:29%;height:23%;background-color:#332334;
border:2px solid red;}
#ThaLabel{position:absolute;top:5%;left:12%;
width:80%;height:19%;background-color:gray;
text-align:center;padding-left:5px;
font-size:14px;color:black;}
#ForTransfer{position:absolute;top:29%;
left:12%;width:60%;height:25%;font-size:19px;
font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;color:red;}
#SendUserData{position:absolute;top:75%;left:72%;
width:20%;height:18%;text-align:center;
padding-left:5px;font-size:14px;color:navy;}


/*
DemJS.js
*/
window.onload=function(){
//  This covers Initial Outgoing OnPageLoad
if (typeof MakeVariableVisibleToJavaScriptOnPageLOAD !== 'undefined') {
        var FillInName = MakeVariableVisibleToJavaScriptOnPageLOAD;
}
FillFormAforhand(FillInName);
}
function FillFormAforhand(FillInName){
var GrabElem;
GrabElem = document.getElementById("ForTransfer");
GrabElem.innerHTML = FillInName;
GrabElem.style = "font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;color:red;";
}
```

Finally, to the last point of your question, you could use a hidden input
to transfer *First Name* as contained in $Label, for use on DemPg2.php.

Cheers!

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

Yes, pretty much got me in the right direction.  I should have done it all in php not javascript...

It is working like crazy!!!

Again thank you for your time, direction, and knowledge.

StackOverFlow does it again!!!